# Integration involving Gaussian kernel

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I need help to solve the integration
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(x^2C+P)e^{\frac{-(x-R)^2}{W^2}}}{1+Ge^{\frac{-(x-R)^2}{W^2}}} dx$$
where C,P,R,G,W are constants
I have tried with Tonelli's theorem but still couldn't solve the integration.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start by simplifying the structure of the integrand function:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(x^2C+P)e^{\frac{-(x-R)^2}{W^2}}}{1+Ge^{\frac{-(x-R)^2}{W^2}}} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(C(|W|x+R)^2+P)e^{-x^2}}{1+Ge^{-x^2}} dx$$

and since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x e^{-x^2}}{1+G e^{-x^2}}\,dx = 0$ by symmetry, everything boils down to the evaluation of two integrals:

$$ I_1(G) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+G e^{-x^2}}\,dx,\qquad I_2(G)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2 e^{-x^2}}{1+G e^{-x^2}}\,dx $$

where, assuming $|G|<1$,
$$ I_1(G) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{dx}{e^x+G}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n G^n e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n G^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}. $$

$I_2(G)$ can be managed in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Recalling that
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2} x^n}{e^{-x^2}+a}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{a e^{x^2}+1}\,dx=\frac 12\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{a e^t+1}\,dt$$
$$\color{blue}{J_n=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2} x^n}{e^{-x^2}+a}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\,
   \text{Li}_{\frac{n+1}{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$

For your problem, letting $x=Wt+R$, we have
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}  \left(C (Wt+R )^2+P\right)W}{1+G e^{-t^2}}\,dt$$ Expanding, we face

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{W \left(C R^2+P\right)}{G+e^{t^2}}\,dt=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,W  \left(C R^2+P\right)}{G}\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}(-G)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2 C R e^{-t^2} t W^2}{G e^{-t^2}+1}\,dt=0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{C e^{-t^2} t^2 W^3}{G e^{-t^2}+1}\,dt=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,C W^3 }{2 G}\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}(-G)$$  So,

$$I=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } W}{2 G}\Bigg[2 \left(C R^2+P\right)\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}(-G) +C W^2   \text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}(-G) \Bigg]$$

**Edit**

Assuming $|G|<1$ the integrand can write as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n W e^{-(n+1) t^2} \left(C (R+t W)^2+P\right)\,G^n$$
$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} W e^{-(n+1) t^2} \left(C (R+t W)^2+P\right)\,dt$$ $$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } W \left(2 (n+1) \left(C R^2+P\right)+C W^2\right)}{2 (n+1)^{3/2}}$$ which is what @Jack D'Aurizio wrote.